# sprintf_s generates random number

Tags: php, c++

I have problem with sprintf_s function. I have declared variable 
  char postRequest[512] = "";

Now I used this function to format my variable:

```
sprintf_s(postRequest,
"GET /query/add.php?name=%s&port=%i&qport=%i&players=%i&maxplayers=%i HTTP/1.1\r\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n"
"Host: xxxxxx-xxx.eu\r\n"
"\r\n", svrname, port, qport, 0, maxplayers);
```

Variable svrname is std::string, other variables are all integers.
Now, port has value 27015, qport 27016 and maxplayers 32.
But this is my problem, only maxplayers got value 32 on my DB. Sorry for my english, just look at this image: http://prntscr.com/2gpa0b

Also, this is my PHP script to handle adding those values to table:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("","","","");
ini_set("display_errors","on");
echo $_GET['port'];
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO servers (name, port, maxplayers, players,ip, qport) VALUES('".$_GET['name']."','".$_GET['port']."','".$_GET['maxplayers']."','0','".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."','".$_GET['qport']."')");
```

Hope you know what I mean. Ive checked those values in code before and after sprintf_s, everything was OK, so there must be some problem in my code.

Thanks in forward.

FIXED:
Okay, fixed. Thanks for help.
svrname.c_str() was needed.

Comment: Compile with all warnings. `sprintf_s` is probably not standard C++, and might need witrh `%s` format specifier a `char*` string, not a `std::string` one. So use `.c_str()` method.

Comment: Thank you, it works, I've totally forgot about c_str().

Comment: Mind I asking why I get - reputation points? I'm sorry for my English or maybe beginner mistakes I've done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `%d` for integer, and `%s` for `.c_str()` of `std::string`.

```
sprintf_s(postRequest,
 "GET /query/add.php?name=%s&port=%d&qport=%d&players=%d&maxplayers=%d HTTP/1.1\r\n"
 "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n"
 "Host: xxxxxx-xxx.eu\r\n"
 "\r\n", svrname.c_str(), port, qport, 0, maxplayers);
```